# How can I record music from a MIDI keyboard with a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, music, recording, midi

I would like to use our MacBook Pro to record music my daughter plays on her MIDI keyboard as well as her voice. What kind of hardware/software do I need for this?

Answer (score 2):

There are many brands of MIDI to USB adapters available on the market. They cost about US$40 or less. Here is one example, the [M-Audio Uno](http://www.m-audio.com/products/en_us/Uno.html).

[image]

She can record her performances on [GarageBand](http://www.apple.com/ilife/garageband/), which is a piece of Apple software that comes free with the MacBook Pro.

Comment: Thanks!  Will see about getting one and investigating how GarageBand works.  I may be back!